# PhD interview before applications deadline

Tags: phd, interview

Is it a good sign that I was invited in PhD interview before applications deadline? Or it doesn't mean something?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

When I have seen that happen, it was done to spread the load. The number of interviews can get quite large, and organizing them quite a challenge. Spreading them out over a larger time period reduces the organizational problems. So I would not over interpret it.